# angular 8 jest test `toHaveBeenCalledWith` fails, how to test api url calls?

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular8, angular-test

In my test spec, I would like to insure 2 stuffs.

```
1. dummy data maching with model and get response.
2. find the `api` called with correct url.
```

I am trying those, but getting error as:

`SubsystemServiceService › get susbsytem collection › should call get the subsytem collection`

as well i would like to update my spec file to insure the both my requirement. any one please help  me out here?

here is my spec.ts file:

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { cold } from 'jasmine-marbles';
import { ModelSubSystem } from './../models/model.subSystem';
import { SubsystemService } from './subsystem-service';

describe('SubsystemServiceService', () => {

    let service: SubsystemService;
    let http: HttpClient;

    const data1 = {
        Id: 0,
        Name: 'subsystem1',
        IsDeletePossible: true,
        CreatedBy: '',
        CreatedDate: new Date(),
        UpdatedBy: '',
        UpdatedDate: new Date(),
        UpdatedByName: '',
        CreatedByName: ''
    } as ModelSubSystem;

    const data2 = {
        Id: 0,
        Name: 'subsystem2',
        IsDeletePossible: true,
        CreatedBy: '',
        CreatedDate: new Date(),
        UpdatedBy: '',
        UpdatedDate: new Date(),
        UpdatedByName: '',
        CreatedByName: ''
    } as ModelSubSystem;

    const subsystems = [data1, data2];

    beforeEach(() => {

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [{ provide: HttpClient, useValue: { get: jest.fn() } }]
        });

        service = TestBed.get(SubsystemService);
        http = TestBed.get(HttpClient);

    });

    describe('get susbsytem collection', () => {

        it('should call get the subsytem collection', () => {

            const response = cold('(-a|)', { a: subsystems });
            http.get = jest.fn(() => response);

            expect(http.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`https://ewsanedevaoscmsapi01-as.websites.net/api/SubSystem`);

        });
    });

    it('should be created', () => {
        expect(service).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is your actual action? In a test there should be three things

### Preparation

describe('get susbsytem collection', () => {

```
    it('should call get the subsytem collection', () => {

        const response = cold('(-a|)', { a: subsystems });
        http.get = jest.fn(() => response);
```

### Execution

So you need to perform some action and then check the outcome. Something like

```
service.get();
```

### Assertion

```
        expect(http.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith(`https://ewsanedevaoscmsapi01-as.websites.net/api/SubSystem`);

    });
});
```

### Explanation

Imagine that you want to test the following method of a service:

```
getSubsystems() {
    // Some code lead
    // ...
    // One path leads to get
    if (some condition)
        return http.get('url');
}
```

In order to test the scenario

```
it('should call the url when some condition is fulfilled')
```

you need to:
1. Setup the conditions so that 'some condition' is fulfilled
2. Create the mock response and the spy `const response = cold('(-a|)', { a: subsystems });`
3. Create a service instance and call the code to test `getSubsystems()`
4. Assert that after you called the code, the http.get has been called with the expected argument.

If you don't do the 3, the test framework does not know which unit (method) to execute and so executes nothing.

Comment: adding `service.get();` ok or need to call real service? for my case `service.getSubsystem()` - can you confirm please?

Comment: I added `service.getSubSystems();` -it works fine. got passed. thanking you. as well can you please explain me what's happening here really?

Comment: @Athansios kataras, - i agree.  so when i do the `CRUD` test, how to check `create`,`update` and `delete`?

Comment: You mean post, put and delete from your api; Since this is unit test, you can only check that the calls have been made. They should be isolated from the implementation of the CRUD functionality. If you want to do end to end tests, then you should have a retrieval API and code all the logic to create/update/delete and assert what your retrieval api has returned. If you did a delete then nothing, if you did a create then the info should be returned, etc.